# How pagination works and how it helps in reducing response time when dealing with millions of records?

Tags: java, oracle, pagination

I am working on a trading application which is deployed on Weblogic and  has a limitation that any request that takes more than one minute in processing is killed automatically. The restriction is set at the kernel level and is not application dependent, and is not in our control to change.

There is a search functionality in my application which fails when queried for more than 100 records during a given time frame, and I was assigned a task to see the possible  solutions.

The first approach that I suggested was to use pagination instead of querying for all records at the same time. I was told that it won't help as on the database side it would any ways fetch all records at the same time. This was new for me as I had the understanding until now that this is handled on the database side and the query fetches only  given number of records per page, and with each previous and next it handles it reducing the overall response time.

I did search a lot before posting this query on how pagination works and how it helps reduce the response time but did not get a concrete answer. So would be really great if somebody can help me explain this. Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Pagination done badly will suck the performance out of your application. But it can be implemented efficiently. Use The Index Luke has lots of advice on pagination in SQL. [Check it out](https://use-the-index-luke.com/blog/2013-07/pagination-done-the-postgresql-way)

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. What kind of answer do you expect? If you have read a lot about this subject, what exactly do you not understand?

Comment: @krokodilko  yes I understand your concern. but from all the readings I did, I did not find a concrete answer to help me understand how it works and why it does not help in terms of response time. the accepted answer gave me just that with examples of both key based and non key based pagination which was something I was looking for with less theory and straight to the point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The first approach that I suggested was to use pagination instead of querying for all records at the same time. I was told that it won't help as on the database side it would any ways fetch all records at the same time

This is true if you are using LIMIT and OFFSET clause in your query for pagination. In this case, database loads the matched records(matched with WHERE clause) from disk and then applies OFFSET and LIMIT clause. Since databases use B-tree for indexing, it doesn't know to jump to OFFSET record directly without loading matched records to memory.

To load only the page size records, you need to use `key based pagination`. In this approach we avoid OFFSET clause, instead we use the `key` of record and LIMIT clause.

**Example for key-based pagination:**

Let's say you want to paginate the users

Request for first 10 records:

```
 select * from user where userid > 0 order by userid asc limit 10
```

Let's say last userid in above query is 10.

Request for next 10 records:

```
select * from user where userid > 10 order by userid asc limit 10
```